# password_hash() PASSWORD_DEFAULT PHP 5.5

Tags: php

From password_hash() function:

> PASSWORD_DEFAULT - Use the bcrypt algorithm (default as of PHP 5.5.0).
>   Note that this constant is designed to change over time as new and
>   stronger algorithms are added to PHP. For that reason, the length of
>   the result from using this identifier can change over time. Therefore,
>   it is recommended to store the result in a database column that can
>   expand beyond 60 characters (255 characters would be a good choice).

Does this means whenever PASSWORD_DEFAULT changes i wont be able to use the new php versions because otherwise password_verify() won't be able to correctly check the old user password?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, password_verify() will recognise the algorithm used, because it's embedded in the hash that you're verifying against: that's what the first part of the hash (e.g. `$2y$`) indicates

Comment: I would add to this that you can use `password_needs_rehash` http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php to determine if your old password needs to be rehashed, you can then update old password

Comment: That's what i thought but i wasn't sure if password_verify could recognise the old (not yet) algorithm. Thanks