# How can PHP Hash method change?

Tags: php, algorithm, hash

On PHP's site here: [`http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php`](http://php.net/manual/en/password.constants.php), this following is stated:

> **PASSWORD_DEFAULT** ([integer](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php))
>   The default algorithm to use for hashing if no algorithm is provided. This may change in newer PHP releases when newer, stronger hashing algorithms are supported.
>
> It is worth noting that over time this constant can (and likely will) change. Therefore you should be aware that the length of the resulting hash can change. Therefore, if you use **PASSWORD_DEFAULT** you should store the resulting hash in a way that can store more than 60 characters (255 is the recomended width).

How can this be?  If someone sets their password, and the hash is set in the database, and then the method changes, they will not be able to get in, since the method will produce a different hash, will it not?

Comment: well then dont use PASSWORD_DEFAULT. you think they should keep using an unsafe algorithm to ensure backwards comparability?

Comment: @Dagon password_verify() **is** backwards compatible.

Comment: Just searching for `PASSWORD_DEFAULT` already gives 181 results. Fortunately you don't have to read them all. The [second one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28033298/password-hash-password-default-php-5-5) is already a duplicate of your question. Asked just 5 days ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you hash a password using the hash_password() function, information about the used algorithm and cost is included in the return string. Therefore, password_verify() can always check whether a provided password is valid given a certain hash.

See the docs for [password_hash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php):

> The used algorithm, cost and salt are returned as part of the hash. Therefore, all information that's needed to verify the hash is included in it. This allows the password_verify() function to verify the hash without needing separate storage for the salt or algorithm information.

There's also the function [password_needs_rehash()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-needs-rehash.php) which can be used to check whether a certain hash has been computed with an old algorithm, in which case a new hash has to be computed. Since at the time of a login the password is available as plaintext, you can (and should) at that moment rehash the password if needed.

The warning in the docs about the value changing over time is to make users aware that the length of the computed hash may change. However, the functions are intended to be backwards compatible with older (typically shorter) hashes.